# S3 bucket global uniqueness

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

I have been trying to reason why an S3 bucket name has to be globally unique. I came across the stackoverflow answer as well that says in order to resolve host header, bucket name got to be unique. However, my point is can't AWS direct the s3-region.amazonaws.com to region specific web server that can serve the bucket object from that region? That way the name could be globally unique only for a region. Meaning, the same bucket could be created in a different region. Please let me know if my understanding is completely wrong on how name resolution works or otherwise?

Comment: @Ali - Its a strict requirements (From security and compliance perspective) that S3 *must* keep the data within the region specified by the customer unless and until the customer himself replicates the objects to other region(s). Otherwise it will be a huge violation. To your point, the replication happens within multiple S3 data nodes though in order to achieve 11 9s durability and 4 nines availability.

Comment: Good question. I "believe" this is due to a legacy limitation of AWS implementation, not to forget that S3 was one of the initial services launched by them. Shaking that fundamental premise up (unique bucket names) might cause stir in running systems. Like how we have seen (first ELB, then ELBv2); I'm not surprised if they launch S3 v2 or something behaving more naturally (like you mentioned).

Comment: At its core... The bucket name has to be globally unique because that is how Amazon S3 has been designed. If you want to know _why_ they designed it that way, then I believe there are [many job openings in the Amazon S3 team](https://www.amazon.jobs/en/search?base_query=s3+sde) where you'd learn the innards of S3!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is not, strictly speaking, a technical reason why the bucket namespace absolutely had to be global.  In fact, it technically isn't *quite* as global as most people might assume, because S3 has three distinct partitions that are completely isolated from each other and do not share the same global bucket namespace across partition boundaries—the partitions are `aws` (the global collection of regions most people know as "AWS"), `aws-us-gov` (US GovCloud), and `aws-cn` (the Beijing and Ningxia isolated regions).

So things could have been designed differently, with each region independent, but that is irrelevant now, because the global namespace is entrenched.

But why?

The specific reasons for the global namespace aren't publicly stated, but almost certainly have to do with the evolution of the service, backwards compatibility, and ease of adoption of new regions.

S3 is one of the oldest of the AWS services, older than even EC2.  They almost certainly did not foresee how large it would become.

Originally, the namespace was global of necessity because there weren't multiple regions.  S3 had a single logical region (called "US Standard" for a long time) that was in fact comprised of at least two physical regions, in or near us-east-1 and us-west-2.  You didn't know or care which physical region each upload went to, because they replicated back and forth, transparently, and latency-based DNS resolution automatically gave you the endpoint with the lowest latency.  Many users never knew this detail.

You could even explicitly override the automatic geo-routing of DNS amd upload to the east using the `s3-external-1.amazonaws.com` endpoint or to the west using the `s3-external-2.amazonaws.com` endpoint, but your object would shortly be accessible from either endpoint.

Up until this point, S3 did not offer immediate read‐after‐write consistency on new objects since that would be impractical in the primary/primary, circular replication environment that existed in earlier days.

Eventually, S3 launched in other AWS regions as they came online, but they designed it so that a bucket in any region could be accessed as `${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com`.
This used DNS to route the request to the correct region, based on the bucket name in the hostname, and S3 maintained the DNS mappings.  `*.s3.amazonaws.com` was (and still is) a wildcard record that pointed everything to "S3 US Standard" but S3 would create a CNAME for your bucket that overrode the wildcard and pointed to the correct region, automatically, a few minutes after bucket creation.  Until then, S3 would return a temporary HTTP redirect.  This, obviously enough, requires a global bucket namespace.  It still works for all but the newest regions.

But why did they do it that way?  After all, at around the same time S3 also introduced endpoints in the style `${bucket}.s3-${region}.amazonaws.com` ¹ that are actually wildcard DNS records: `*.s3-${region}.amazonaws.com` routes directly to the regional S3 endpoint for each S3 region, and is a responsive (but unusable) endpoint, even for nonexistent buckets.  If you create a bucket in us-east-2 and send a request for that bucket to the eu-west-1 endpoint, S3 in eu-west-1 will throw an error, telling you that you need to send the request to us-east-2.

Also, around this time, they quietly dropped the whole east/west replication thing, and later renamed US Standard to what it really was at that point—us-east-1.  (Buttressing the "backwards compatibility" argument, s3-external-1 and s3-external-2 are still valid endpoints, but they both point to precisely the same place, in us-east-1.)

So why did the bucket namespace remain global?  The only truly correct answer an outsider can give is "because that's what they decided to do."

But perhaps one factor was that AWS wanted to preserve compatibility with existing software that used `${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com` so that customers could deploy buckets in other regions without code changes.  In the old days of Signature Version 2 (and earlier), the code that signed requests did not need to know the API endpoint region.  Signature Version 4 requires knowledge of the endpoint region in order to generate a valid signature because the signing key is derived against the date, region, and service... but previously it wasn't like that, so you could just drop in a bucket name and client code needed no regional awareness—or even awareness that S3 even had regions—in order to work with a bucket in any region.

AWS is well‐known for its practice of preserving backwards compatibility.  They do this so consistently that occasionally some embarrassing design errors creep in and remain unfixed because to fix them would break running code.²

Another issue is virtual hosting of buckets.  Back before HTTPS was accepted as non‐optional, it was common to host static content by pointing your CNAME to the S3 endpoint.  If you pointed `www.example.com` to S3, it would serve the content from a bucket with the exact name `www.example.com`.  You can still do this, but it isn't useful any more since it doesn't support HTTPS.  To host static S3 content with HTTPS, you use CloudFront in front of the bucket.  Since CloudFront rewrites the `Host` header, the bucket name can be anything.  You might be asking why you couldn't just point the `www.example.com` CNAME to the endpoint hostname of your bucket, but HTTP and DNS operate at very different layers and it simply doesn't work that way.  (If you doubt this assertion, try pointing a CNAME from a domain that you control to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).  You will not find that your domain serves the Google home page; instead, you'll be greeted with an error because the Google server will only see that it's received a request for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), and be oblivious to the fact that there was an intermediate CNAME pointing to it.)  Virtual hosting of buckets requires *either* a global bucket namespace (so the `Host` header exactly matches the bucket) or an entirely separate mapping database of hostnames to bucket names... and why do that when you already have an established global namespace of buckets?

---

¹ Note that the `-` after `s3` in these endpoints was eventually replaced by a much more logical `.` but these old endpoints still work.

² two examples that come to mind: (1) S3's incorrect omission of the `Vary: Origin` response header when a non-CORS request arrives at a CORS-enabled bucket (I have argued without success that this can be fixed without breaking anything, to no avail); (2) S3's blatantly incorrect handling of the symbol `+` in an object key, on the API, where the service interprets `+` as meaning `%20` (space) so if you want a browser to download from a link to `/foo+bar` you have to upload it as `/foo{space}bar`.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive and logical explanation. Thats exactly what I was looking for. Esp that backward compatibility point of yours with s3.amazonaws.com and SigV2!! Thanks heaps!

Comment: Great answer, but can you clarify, "It still works for all but the newest regions." When does it not work? (P.S. I think your explanation of HTTPS is wrong. The certificate simply lists the wrong domain, it has nothing to do global buckets. Also you're completely wrong about the `+`. The browser interprets it itself as a space, not the service. You have to use `%2B` in the browser, exactly as the S3 console directs you to.)

Answer (score 3):

You create an S3 bucket in a specific region only and objects stored in a bucket is only stored in that region itself. The  data is neither replicated nor stored in different regions, unless you setup replication on a per bucket basis.

However. AWS S3 shares a global name space with all accounts. The name given to an S3 bucket should be unique

This requirement is designed to support globally unique DNS names for each bucket eg. `http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com`

Comment: Agreed. Similarly, commands like `aws s3 ls s3://bucketname` do not require specification of the region. If bucket name were unique per region, then every reference to a bucket would need to also reference the region.

Comment: @Rodrigo - Understand. However, the question now is why bucket should have a unique DNS? Why can't it work the way lets say Dynamo DB works where I ask it to get me items from **a region**. Shouldn't s3-region.amazonaws.com resolve into a specific region's web server and serve me the objects from the bucket from that region?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - s3 cli are the after effect of this architecture. It may not address my core question/doubt.